# HTML : Photo swipe is not workling

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to implement photoswipe.js for swipe images in  but swipe is not working.

**head**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/klass.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/code.photoswipe-3.0.4.min.js">       </script>


 <script type="text/javascript">
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, true);

function onDeviceReady() {
   // related functions
     alert("check");
   $("#Gallery a").photoSwipe();
} 
(function(window, PhotoSwipe){

    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){

        var
            options = {},
            instance = PhotoSwipe.attach(    window.document.querySelectorAll('#Gallery a'), options );

    }, false);


}(window, window.Code.PhotoSwipe));

</script>
```

**body**

```
<ul id="Gallery" class="gallery">
<li><a href="img/img1.jpg"><img src="img/img1.jpg" rel="external" alt="" />   </a></li>
<li><a href="img/img2.jpg"><img src="img/img2.jpg" rel="external"  alt="" /></a></li>

</ul>
```

Can any one please tell me where I made the mistake.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Check Have any error in console

Comment: no error in console @ Junaid Ahmed

Answer (score 0):

I think your cordova loading completed before DOM loads, so add
document.addEvenListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, true); line 
inside document load function.